# why the hatred....only here

Tags: discussion

why the hatred?  Only on askubuntu is just about every question down-voted.  take this:

[failed to start dockerd after installing docker with snap (artful, 17.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977961/failed-to-start-dockerd-after-installing-docker-with-snap-artful-17-10)

even when there is a comment, like "what is the environment", generally that's *in* the question.  There's nothing wrong with the question.

Blah.

It's unique to this specific stack overflow site.  Sure, I get down-voted questions -- maybe even more than my fair share.

My *perception* is that, at least recently, most every single question on askubuntu get's an initial downvote.  sometimes this is canceled out to a zero, and that's fine.

(For what it's worth, the rep/score isn't my concern, it's more that a down-voted question will garner fewer responses -- presumably.)

It's possible that my perception is off.  It just *seems* that someone(s) following my questions and downvoting them.  hey, maybe I annoy them.  I dunno.

If it's random and or deserved then so be it.  But I notice tha my questions on, particularly, linux stackoverflow, are better received.  Maybe I just ask better questions there.  But maybe not.

I would expect the standards to be about the same.

Comment: I downvoted this one because it is mostly a rant. I am on mobile, so can't see much of your activity but what I can shows about 100 questions by you with just a few downvoted ones and just as many highly upvoted ones, I don't see hatred or excessive downvoting. If a single user is downvoting you, the system will revert it.

Comment: Maybe your answers on Linux & Unix Q&A were upvoted more because they are higher quality answers. I remember reading one of your answers recently on Unix & Linux Q&A and I was impressed with it and thought to myself, wow this guy posts better answers on Unix & Linux Q&A than he does on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: For every question that gets downvoted, check every single section of https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and ask yourself to what extent your question answers to it.

Comment: I was the one that downvoted the question you cite. I did this because you neither describe your situation nor asked a clear question, but merely added not even cleaned (I then did that for you) terminal output  with lots of unneeded information. The full output of `lsb_release -a` for example is fine, but it's unclear what you want to say with it. If that's just “I use 17.10.” then why don't you just write *this* instead of forcing potential answerers to dig through this pile of terminal output and merely guess what exactly you did and want?

Comment: Btw [this question of you on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405576/246819) has the exact same problems and also got downvoted because of that – and not by me, rest assured.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your perception is indeed wrong. At least with respect to the sites you mentioned:

```
Site           Total Qs    Downvoted Qs    Percentage
Ask Ubuntu      238559      13251             5.55
Unix & Linux    118261      9744              8.24
Stack Overflow  14258884    1676744           11.76
```

The table above shows<sup>1</sup> the total number of questions asked in the past month (since 20-10-2017), the number of those that have been downvoted and what percentage of the total questions have been downvoted. As you can see, this site is actually the one with the lowest percentage of downvoted questions, not the highest as you are suggesting.

And these are the statistics of your own questions (all the questions you've asked on these sites):

```
Site            Total Qs    Downvoted Qs   Percentage
Ask Ubuntu       149            12            8.05
Unix & Linux     66             5             7.58
Stack Overflow   344            23            6.69
```

So yes, you do seem to have a slightly higher percentage of downvoted questions on AU, but the difference is negligible. At least with respect to U&L, anyway. But even when comparing to SO, the difference is 0.013, which can't really be called "large".

So, in conclusion, I'm afraid the numbers don't support your perception that you're being downvoted significantly more here than on other sites.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I used these two data.se queries to get the numbers:
 [Total Questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/760878/total-questions), [Downvoted Questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/760878/downvoted-questions).</sub>

Comment: thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

## Hatred?

#### There is no hatred here, only love...

... for <s>the Almighty</s> Ubuntu (And to be honest: Yes we don't like Kali questions nor Minty ones but to investigate something we need some more than your original question contained, corrected in the meantime)

[image]

Maybe there is **one** disgruntled, hateful person that wants to leave the community, cannot get rid of his/her rep and decided to act like a royal pain in the lower abdomen, maybe someone doesn't like your handle, maybe someone knows you personally and is following you around trying to make you upset, ...

<sub>Also, most of us are experts on Ubuntu, most of us are not experts on Docker...  Give your question some time, add a bounty, ...</sub>

Comment: it's the pattern.  almost every question, at least recently, on ask ubuntu gets an initial down vote.  it's the pattern.  annoying.

Comment: Please state that in your question.  Maybe there is **one** disgruntled, hateful person that wants to leave the community, cannot get rid of his/her rep and decided to act like a royal pain in the lower abdomen...

Comment: good point on the bounty.  thx.

Comment: You're Welcome. Have one upvote to counteract the dumb downvote...

Comment: @Thufir I would like the voting system to be radically different then what it is today as well, but alas, it is what it is and you shouldn't take it personally... (which is hard, I know...)